# com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.exception.PlaylistDownloadException:

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

[image]

I created the following Test Scenario under Ubuntu:

- Thread 100 Vus
- Ram-Up Period Time:400s
- Loop:1
- BZM-Streaming Sampler (video Duration:12seconds)
- Jmeter Version:5.2.1
- HLS Pluging 3.0 Version

When I run the Test , I got the following Exception:

```
com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.exception.PlaylistDownloadException: Problem downloading master https://damxdcfpo.maxdome.de/mxd-manifest-service/mxd-mediavault-prod/540e30_18928950_2017-08-09_02-49/18928950.ism/.mpd?session_id=1007560909-1171436075-ddb54&filter=(type==%22video%22%26%26MaxHeight%3C=576)%7C%7C(type==%22audio%22%26%26FourCC==%22AACL%22)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.VideoStreamingSampler.downloadPlaylist(VideoStreamingSampler.java:106) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.dash.DashSampler.sample(DashSampler.java:34) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.VideoStreamingSampler.sample(VideoStreamingSampler.java:79) [jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.hls.logic.HlsSampler.sample(HlsSampler.java:184) [jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1271) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using:

- latest stable [JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html)
- HLS plugin [3.0.1](https://github.com/Blazemeter/HLSPlugin/tree/v3.0.1)

[image]

Consider upgrading to the HLS plugin 3.0.1, it can be done using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/). Just in case re-install JMeter as well in order to avoid possible [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)

Comment: thank you Dimitri...but I still have the same problem, though I updated the HLS Plugin 3.0.1... I start my test with 100Vus and 300s as Rampup Time, and 1 Loop....I think you run your test with 1 Thread

Comment: If the issue occurs only under the load then either your application is overloaded and cannot send a proper mpeg-dash playlist or JMeter is overloaded and cannot properly parse the server's response. First of all try [saving response data for failed samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/) and look what you're getting and then consider using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) to monitor the resources usage on server and JMeter sides

Comment: @Dimitri...Thanx

Comment: this is the exception what I get now after saving the response in csv file:

Comment: ``` bzm - Streaming Sampler - master,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to damxdcfpo.maxdome.de:443 [damxdcfpo.maxdome.de/13.227.198.98, damxdcfpo.maxdome.de/13.227.198.61, damxdcfpo.maxdome.de/13.227.198.121, damxdcfpo.maxdome.de/13.227.198.21] failed: Connection timed out: connect",Thread Group 1-67,text,false,,3424,0,92,92,```

Comment: `bzm - Streaming Sampler - video init segment,Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException,Non HTTP response message: Received close_notify during handshake,Thread Group 1-70,text,false,,3695,0,93,93,